# SQL illegal maxField value: 1024, Is it jdbc issue or cnosdb issue?

Tags: java, jdbc, cnosdb

I am adding cnosdb jdbc use case, the code as follow

```
    @Test
    public void test_Jdbc_field_size() throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:arrow-flight-sql://localhost:8904";
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", "root"); //用户名
        properties.put("password", "");  //密码
        properties.put("tenant", "cnosdb");//租户
        properties.put("db", "public");// db
        properties.put("useEncryption", false);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        int rs003 = stmt.getMaxFieldSize();
        assertTrue(rs003 == 0);
        stmt.setMaxFieldSize(1024);
        
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

the result always, as follow

```
SQL illegal maxField value: 1024
```

I check the doc,as

`The maxFieldSize limit (in bytes) is set to limit the size of data that can be returned for any column value; it only applies to BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, CHAR, VARCHAR, and LONGVARCHAR fields. If the limit is exceeded, the excess data is silently discarded. For maximum portability use values greater than 256.`

flight-sql-jdbc-driver:12.0.1, arrow-jdbc:12.0.1

Comment: You can set maxFieldSize if your current Statement Implementation supports that. For Instance here
 https://github.com/apache/calcite-avatica/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/avatica/AvaticaStatement.java#L286
you will get similar Exception

Comment: This is the driver, because in the JDBC API, `Statement` is an interface, and `setMaxFieldSize` does not have a default implementation, so any errors are provided by the implementation (i.e. the JDBC driver). However, I'd be curious to know **why** are you trying to set it? In general, there is no good reason to set it (and support between JDBC drivers is spotty at best).